# Recover data from Mac Os APFS volume using Ubuntu

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

Finder has a bad habit of corrupting external disks. In about 2 months, 2 brand new disks were corrupted by my lovely Mac. The data is there; I installed data recovery software and it shows everything is there, but dumb mac Os won't mount the disks.

Here's my question: How can I do this on my own? The data recovery software is able to find my files by scanning the raw data on the disk. If I could figure out what tools or commands it uses, then i'd be able to do it on my own.

Some research suggests booting my machine on Linux, then using the DD command to access the data on disks. Anyone familiar with this?

Answer (score 0):

I am doing a data recovery job now.  The apfs contrived by the capitalist entity apple has apparently set its users in an even smaller box than the cage they were in just a few years ago (pre-apfs).

I can tell you this, so far I see only marginal success using a linux utility called "photorec" which is part of the "testdisk" utility.

However I'm told that amongst the hundreds of files recovered, that not all the files were recovered and so I'm attempting to do the recovery again.  The owner of the mac died and her sister is wanting to recover her dead sister's files and especially the genealogy tree and journal that she had made.  The living sister was hoping that she would be able to simply look through folders and filenames as they were made by her sister, photorec does not do this and testdisk is a dead-end in that endeavor (as of 2021).

Her sister's drive is intact and boots to the apple password screen just fine, but nobody knows the password in her family and the "hint" so far has not helped. The deceased owner apparently was duped by a mac pop-up that went something like this: "your apple is unsecure, click here to make it secure", and invariably the user is not able to see any number of scenarios where a proprietary lock-down is outrageous.  In her life I'm going to guess that she's not had one solitary person steal her mac, so it only locks the owner (if the owner should forget the password) or those that would pay people like me to access the drive remotely.

In the pre-apfs I could simply run a few scripts and bi-pass all security, this method apparently is not working with apfs.

In closing,
I've said it before and I'll say it again, every mac and microsoft user that requires help with their defunct crippled os should be lauding the efforts of all the opensource software makers out there (that SHARE their creations with the world freely), otherwise we'd all be in a rut paying off the rut-master bookoo forgetaboutit bucks.
Get linux and be done with this sort of illusions of safety.
RIP

Sorry I can't help you at this moment.  If you want to invest in the capitalists that are selling their wares to recover, google: apfs file recovery and make sure you're wearing your waders.

Comment: I posted a solution using APFS-fuse on Ubuntu. I bashed the idiotic mods for judging instead of answering, so it looks they took it down. You need to install APFS-Fuse on Ubuntu and mount the disk. I had to create a bootable Ubuntu USB stick for my mac, and from there I installed APFS-Fuse and was able to access the data from one disk as read-only. I agree, do not use APFS, it's crap